# python midpoint line clipping algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, graphics, geometry

This midpoint algorithm in python(2.7) doesn't work. He isn't go out of recursion. Where is the mistake? Please help me.

```
# Where is point
def vcode(rect, p):
    value = 0
    if p.x < rect.x_min:
        value += LEFT
    if p.x >= rect.x_max:
        value += RIGHT
    if p.y < rect.y_min:
        value += BOT
    if p.y >= rect.y_max:
        value += TOP

    return value

# algorithm
def average_point(rect, p1, p2, count=0):
    code_a = vcode(rect, p1)
    code_b = vcode(rect, p2)
    if math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)) < EPS:
        return
    if not (code_a | code_b):
        return
    if code_a & code_b:
        return
    mid = Point((p2.x+p1.x)/2.0, (p2.y+p1.y)/2.0)
    count += 1
    average_point(rect, p1, mid, count)
    mid.x = mid.x+1
    mid.y = mid.y+1
    average_point(rect, mid, p2, count)
    return count
```

p1, p2 is `Point( class, fields(x, y));`

rect is `Rectangle( class, fields(x_min, y_min, x_max, y_max));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code works fine, except it is returning the final value of `count` when the method is first called. Therefore, `count` will always be 1. To correct this, you need to set `count` to the return value of `average_point`. Then, your code will look like:

```
# algorithm
def average_point(rect, p1, p2, count=0):
    returnArray = []
    code_a = vcode(rect, p1)
    code_b = vcode(rect, p2)
    if math.sqrt((p2.x - p1.x) * (p2.x - p1.x) + (p2.y - p1.y) * (p2.y - p1.y)) < EPS:
        returnArray.append(count)
        returnArray.append(p1)
        returnArray.append(p2)
        return returnArray
    if not (code_a | code_b):
        returnArray.append(count)
        returnArray.append(p1)
        returnArray.append(p2)
        return returnArray
    if code_a & code_b:
        returnArray.append(count)
        returnArray.append(p1)
        returnArray.append(p2)
        return returnArray
    mid = Point((p2.x+p1.x)/2.0, (p2.y+p1.y)/2.0)
    count += 1
    returnArray = average_point(rect, p1, mid, count)
    mid.x = mid.x+1
    mid.y = mid.y+1
    returnArray = average_point(rect, mid, p2, count)
    return returnArray
```

This will replace the `count` value every iteration, and **make sure you add the `return count`s in because otherwise it will not receive the correct value.**

This also include the points in indexes 1 and 2 because in python you can have multiple "types" in arrays so you can return both points and the count.

Comment: He actually has three conditions to break out of the recursion. But obviously none is ever met.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Ah true... missed that

Comment: @Wolkodav what is the value of `EPS`?

Comment: Not big value. EPS=1. I compare the length of line and minimal lines.

Comment: Task is: How many times is a division of the interval, the algorithm. Then i most compare this results with other. But sometimes this function does not go out of recursion, and i get "count" always equal 1(

Comment: @Wolkodav Are you running this through the shell?

Comment: Not always. Sometimes pycharm.

Comment: @Wolkodav Check edits. You forgot to reassign `count` each iteration so it would always return 1.

Comment: @OutlawLemur, thaks, this work! And how I can get my new points? After work this function?

Comment: @Wolkodav you could have it return an array, with the points positions, and the count. Then when you reassign `count` you take the first index (0) to find the count only.

Comment: I got a array of points, i wont get only to points, which i wont found.

Comment: @Wolkodav What do you mean?

Comment: @Wolkodav check edits. You can return multiple "types" (python doesn't have definite types on objects) so you can return the whole `Point` object